# Convert the MySQL explain plan to string

Tags: mysql, explain, sql-execution-plan

I need to convert this

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | prueba2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9791 |       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

to a string into the mysql DBM to read just this string in an external system.

I need as least this part as a string

```
|  1 | SIMPLE      | prueba2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9791 |       |
```

Comment: Step 1: Select the row. Step 2: Copy. Step 3: Paste into an insert statement.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? Is there any reason you can't mysql_dump?

Comment: I think you'll find that an EXPLAIN statement returns a result set just like any other statement that returns a result set. It's up to the client to format the results.

Comment: what suppose to be the result?

Comment: I wanna get a string like the one returned by PostgreSQL's EXPLAIN clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the results to a file via the command line, but you'll need to parse it and format it exactly as you want:

```
mysql -e "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl" -D db -h host -u usr -p pwd > myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about something like this `string(EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl)`, but I guess it's not possible.